# uncheck a checkbox when I check another - laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-5

i have a problem,  i need to uncheck a checkbox when check another checkbox. but checkboxes must not have the same name. the name field must be different.

```
       <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-1">

  <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-2">
```

How can I make them uncheck?

Comment: Why do they need different names? why not just set a value since they have none.

Comment: if ($request->input('custom-radio-2')) {  elseif ($request->input('custom-radio-1'))  because I have two conditions with their name

Comment: So have 1 condition with different values. `if ($request->get('radio-input') == 'radio-value') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can do something like this:

```js
function uncheckAndCheck(event) {

  // gets all radios with the name prefix like 'custom-radio-'
  // and uncheck all of them
  document.querySelectorAll( "input[type='radio'][name^='custom-radio-']" ).forEach( radio => {
    radio.checked = false;
  });
  
  // checks the radio that triggered the click event
  event.target.checked = true;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-1" onclick="uncheckAndCheck(event)"/>
<input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-2" onclick="uncheckAndCheck(event)"/>
```

Comment: This is how you would do this. but he should not. hes essentially checking the names of the inputs being sent through where he should just use the radio inputs how they are intended. different values.

Comment: @MichaelMano no, you are assuming this. His problem is well explained. What he will do with this is his problem, not mine. How do you know that he wants the data in the server side or is something only related to the client?